# Why DialogFragments renders forceclose in Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, datepicker

As I came to know through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) that I need to extend `FragmentActivity rather Activity if **datepicker** is used in older version to  android 3.0. If I run this app it force closes.

In the site it is mentioned that we need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` rather `getFragmentManager()`. If `getFragmentManager()` is used my app crashes and shows error if I use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance here my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     static EditText edit = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");   

            }
        });
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(year).append("/").append(month).append("/").append(day);
        edit.setText(sb);

    }
}
}
```

**the log file**  edited ...

```
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.datetestapp.MainActivity$DatePickerFragment
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.example.datetestapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-25 14:23:26.575: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 14:23:28.654: I/Process(443): Sending signal. PID: 443 SIG: 9
```

Comment: stacktrace of the exception??

Comment: ThankQ very much 4 ur time. DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(); is the line wher I got exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mixed classes from the OS and from the support library. Check your imports to make sure that you only use fragment related classes from the support library like `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.